# Anaconda python keeps using 2.7

Tags: python, anaconda

I am using ubuntu 16.04. I installed [anaconda](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/linux) using `bash ~/Downloads/Anaconda3-5.1.0-Linux-x86_64.sh`.

Then I create a new environment `conda create -n python35 python=3.5 anaconda`

Then I activate `conda activate python35`. Then I launch python by typing `python` but it still says that I am using python 2.7.

**Edit:**

```
$ whereis anaconda
anaconda: /home/haziq/anaconda3/bin/anaconda
```

---

```
$ whereis python 
python: /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python3.5m /usr/bin/python3.5 /usr/bin/python2.7-config /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/lib/python3.5 /usr/lib/python2.7 /etc/python /etc/python3.5 /etc/python2.7 /usr/local/lib/python3.5 /usr/local/lib/python2.7 /usr/include/python3.5m /usr/include/python2.7 /usr/share/python /home/haziq/anaconda3/bin/python /home/haziq/anaconda3/bin/python3.6-config /home/haziq/anaconda3/bin/python3.6 /home/haziq/anaconda3/bin/python3.6m-config /home/haziq/anaconda3/bin/python3.6m /usr/share/man/man1/python.1.gz
```

---

```
$ cat ~/.bashrc

# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)   

# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;; esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1) HISTSIZE=1000 HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS. shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1) [ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below) if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot) fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color) case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;; esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then   # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48     # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such     # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)     color_prompt=yes
    else    color_prompt=
    fi fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ ' else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ ' fi unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir case "$TERM" in xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;; esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto' fi

# colored GCC warnings and errors
#export GCC_COLORS='error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:locus=01:quote=01'

# some more ls aliases alias ll='ls -alF' alias la='ls -A' alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc). if ! shopt -oq posix; then   if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion   elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion   fi fi

# added by Anaconda3 installer 
export PATH="/home/haziq/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"

alias python=python2.7

# added by Anaconda3 installer 
export PATH="/home/haziq/anaconda3/bin:$PATH" 
export PATH="/home/haziq/anaconda3/bin:$PATH" 
export PATH="/home/haziq/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: Run this command may solve your problem `echo export PATH=\"/home/$USER/anaconda3/bin:\$PATH\" >> ~/.bashrc` and then run `source ~/.bashrc`

Comment: does not work..

Comment: Please edit your question and add this commands output `whereis anaconda` and `cat ~/.bashrc`

Comment: And this command `whereis python`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of that you have this line in your `.bashrc` file.

```
alias python=python2.7
```

Remove that line with this command:

```
sed -i.bak '/python=python2.7/d' ~/.bashrc
```

And then run this command:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: I'm glad , I could help you

Comment: Good job Ali, nice to see you track the problem, then provide the solution.